# Reference of CSS when outer element height is auto for percentage based content element heights

Tags: css

If I have a div element with CSS `height` set to `auto`, and all its content height was set to percentage values, then where does the contents of that div based their reference for the height?

Comment: Their contents themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, the contents set their height as if they were set to "auto" rather than percentage values.

See under "<percentage>" at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

i think inherited css attribute will be based on their direct parent container. 
just as a position:absolute element's top,bottom,left,right value will be based on its' direct parent container , instead of root container.